# Bootstrap 4 alpha 6 and card width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

The following code:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-block">
        <form class="row">
            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                <label for="visualTheme" class="control-label">Visual Theme</label>
                <div>
                    <input class="form-control" style="height:30px;" id="visualTheme">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
                <label for="startingScreen" class="control-label">Starting Screen</label>
                <div>
                    <input class="form-control" style="height:30px;" id="startingScreen">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uvrkuk4p/7/)

when using alpha 4 was producing a form that was taking the provided width. But with Alpha 6 it takes approximately a half of available space unless I use a concrete number of px for a style. But I don't want to do it because resizing won't work. Any idea how to specify the width in this situation?

Thanks

That's how it looks in my app:
[image]

Comment: your card and form are taking the provided width, your `.form-group`s are not. Maybe you meant to add `.col-sm-6` instead `.col-sm-4` class

Comment: Just tried .col-sm-6, same thing. Adding an image.

Comment: @mark not sure what you mean "half of available space". Seems to work the same in Alpha 4 and Alpha 6: http://www.codeply.com/go/uwfmj9b7j4

Comment: I think I found the reason. The card is enclosed in multiple divs. In A4 I did not have to specify width:100% for these. But in A6 I have to.